# c++ Why does my getline read all lines from input file before continuing?

Tags: c++, getline

Edit: Simple mistake, I had a comment that separated the first opening bracket from the loop, ending it prematurely.

I have my getline in a while loop. I expected the program to read a single line from getline, then move on to parse that line. Instead it reads all lines from the output right away.

```
int main(){
    char longest_word[MAX] = {0};
    char shortest_word[MAX] = {0};
    char hold_line[MAX] = {0};
    int word_freq[MAX] = {0};
    char wordtable[MAX][MAX] = {0};
    int word_length_table[MAX] = {0};
    char* word_pointer = NULL;
    int index_match, totalword_count = 0, unique_count = 0, line_count = 0;
    ifstream readfile;
    readfile.open("input.txt");
    while ( readfile.getline(hold_line, MAX) )
```

Comment: If you are going to write in C++, why not use `std::string`, `std::cin`, etc?

Comment: Please post your entire while loop.

Comment: It *will* stop at end-of-line, assuming that the text file has a line terminator consistent with the operating system used.

Comment: Edit: Simple mistake, I had a comment that separated the first opening bracket from the loop, ending it prematurely. I'm new to stack overflow, do i need to close this question. if so, how?